# References and footpage

Tags: bibliographies

This is my first question.
I'm writing a report and I want that the `References` of the citations shows in footpage of each page.
I also want my report has a references section shows all references that I use in the end of my reports but without numbers as the 
`\bibliographystyle`
does.

How can I do that with LateX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your are probably looking for `footcites` (which is `biblatex`, however). You can change your `\bibliographystyle` to another style of course

Comment: If don't know whether there's a `\footcite` -like approach for `bibtex`. `biblatex` is perhaps the better alternative. I choose `bibtex` as the backend, to reduce the changes.

Answer (score 2):

This applies `\footcite` from `biblatex` with the `bibtex` backend and citation style `alphabetic`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{mybiblo.bib}
  @article{MBBL2014,
    author = {Ministeriet for by Bolig og Landdistrikter},
    title = {{Matriklens Udvidelse}},
    url = {http://grunddata-ejendom-adresse.dk/matriklens\_udvidelse},
    urldate = {2015-04-20},
    year = {2014} 
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\addbibresource{mybiblo.bib}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footcite{MBBL2014}

%\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]